# Disabling Matlab gui items

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

We're writing a program with several pull downs to sort through data. It's a decent sized dataset, and the pulldowns are generated dynamically. As a result, when you change a pulldown you have to wait a second or five before selecting the next pulldown, or it screws the whole thing up. So, I wrote a small function that disables all the UI elements (sets enable property to off).

The problem is that it isn't working reliably in pulldown callback functions.

```
function deactivate_pulldowns(handles)

set(handles.first_data_field_pulldown,'enable','off');
set(handles.first_key_data_list_pulldown,'enable','off');
set(handles.second_data_field_pulldown,'enable','off');


function first_data_field_pulldown_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

%deactivate the pulldowns until processing is complete
deactivate_pulldowns(handles);

%wipe out the old pull down if it exists
try
    [dummy, dummy] = size(handles.first_field_reduced_key_data);
    handles.first_field_reduced_key_data = '';
    clear handles.first_field_reduced_key_data
catch

% ... This is pretty long and does a bunch of processing and takes time
```

So, the above doesn't work. But, if I add a message box just after the deactivate_pulldowns call, it works fine.

```
function first_data_field_pulldown_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

%deactivate the pulldowns until processing is complete
deactivate_pulldowns(handles);
msgbox('test1');

%wipe out the old pull down if it exists
try
    [dummy, dummy] = size(handles.first_field_reduced_key_data);
    handles.first_field_reduced_key_data = '';
    clear handles.first_field_reduced_key_data
catch

% ... This is pretty long and does a bunch of processing and takes time
```

This will deactivate all the pulldowns like I expect. Whats going on here!?

Comment: Though the uicontrols might not look like they're disabled, they probably are - only their visual appearance isn't updated. Did you try clicking them during the processing? Adding the `msgbox` has the same effect as @chappjc answer - namely enabling a repainting of changed gui-elements.

Comment: I was able to click them. I'm not sure if it actually did anything, however. chappjc's answer did exactly what I needed it to.

Comment: Well, you can obviously always click - the question of course is, if something happens...

Comment: The gui responded. I just don't know if the callback fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to force the user-interface objects to update.  Try [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) in place of the dummy message box:

```
drawnow('update')
```

Or perhaps a full event queue flush with just `drawnow` on its own.